# Calculating joint entropy of two variables having null values

Tags: random-variable, entropy

I calculated the joint entropy of two random discrete variables by zipping their values in a 2-tuple and applying the formula:

[image]

where n is the number of distinct classes and q is the probability of a particular class.

Values of these variables are null at some random points. I handled calculating entropy of one variable by filtering null values and calculating entropy in the same manner as before. However, when it comes to joint entropy of two, I found it confusing. I think I can filter out the value if it is (null, null). What should I do about cases like (value, null) and (null, value)? Should I treat them as classes as well?